# i need animate item when scrolling listview in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

i need somehow animate items in list on scroll.
there is a package auto_animated in pub packages, but problem is that animation start when scroll ends.

[image: scroll_animation]

Comment: You  also use **flutter_staggered_animations** package here https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_animations

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil it seems this package like auto_animated create animations after scroll event ends

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `AnimatedList` Widget, it propably fulfills your needs. Here some resources:

- [flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html)
- [Flutter Widget of the Week](https://youtu.be/ZtfItHwFlZ8)
- [Medium Article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-animate-items-in-list-using-animatedlist-in-flutter-9b1a64e9aa16)

You can set how the items enter the screen and how they leave the screen. If you create a custom animation for it you are propaby good to go.